# Export xml to csv row

Tags: c#, xml, csv

I have the following xml file to give an idea of layout,

```
<weather>
<current_conditions>
<condition data="Mostly Cloudy" /> 
<temp_f data="48" /> 
<temp_c data="9" /> 
<humidity data="Humidity: 71%" /> 
<icon data="/ig/images/weather/mostly_cloudy.gif" /> 
<wind_condition data="Wind: W at 17 mph" /> 
</current_conditions>
<forecast_conditions>
<day_of_week data="Sun" /> 
<low data="34" /> 
<high data="48" /> 
<icon data="/ig/images/weather/mostly_sunny.gif" /> 
<condition data="Partly Sunny" /> 
</forecast_conditions>
<forecast_conditions>
<day_of_week data="Mon" /> 
<low data="32" /> 
<high data="45" /> 
<icon data="/ig/images/weather/sunny.gif" /> 
<condition data="Clear" /> 
</forecast_conditions>
```

I am learning c# and want to export to csv using a row for each day of the week,
where info for a day is not available i need to show no data in the csv row. 
I appreciate the simplest solution as i am learning :)

Comment: I can get the data into a string..

Comment: string day = "Tue";
            string path = "weather/forecast_conditions[day_of_week/@data='" + day + "']/condition";
           string towrite = doc.XPathSelectElement(path).Attribute("data").Value;

Comment: I'd recommend editing your post and putting what you've tried into your question! The more code, the better!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to ignore the *current conditions* node as it doesn't make much sense to me to have a csv file where the columns don't all match the same data. For getting all the forecast info into a csv you can use:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(...);    
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1000);
foreach (XElement node in doc.Descendants("forecast_conditions"))
{
    foreach(XElement innerNode in node.Elements())
    {
       sb.AppendFormat("{0},", innerNode.Attribute("data").Value);
    }
    //Remove trailing comma
    sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);
    sb.AppendLine();
}
File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp.csv", sb.ToString());
```

Comment: this is works thanks, how could i exclude an element for example icon data ?

Comment: Also I don't understand what the "1000" does after stringbuilder? thanks

Comment: Use an if statement on the innerNode object, one of the properties will contain the name of the node. The properties name is most likely Name though I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: The 1000 just sets the default capacity of the StringBuilder. It's not important and can be left out, but check http://www.dotnetperls.com/stringbuilder-capacity if you wish to know more

Comment: Sorry, i don't see how I can use an if statement to exclude a element?

Comment: if(innerNode.Name != "icon"){sb.AppendFormat...}